# Pyinstaller python skip module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-imaging-library

I want to compile python script with PILLOW, but Pyinstaller finds imageqt module and installing to my executable pyqt5 also.

I don't need pyqt5, becouse with pyqt my exe file has ~25mb size.

Can I skip pyqt5 module?

Comment: if pyqt5 is a dependency of imageqt, then i don't think you can "skip" it. Your program would fail.

Comment: ok, thank you for answer